# How to do a JavaFx textfield no focusable?

Tags: javafx

I'm using JavaFx and have a popup window to edit / create.

When the action is to edit, I need that some fields won't be selectables nor editables, what method i can use to do it?

***Note:*** to do no editable, I'm using:

```
fieldname.setEditable(false);
```

Comment: `fieldname.setDisable(true)`

Comment: @fabion, ok. `setDisable(true)` works fine!